# SFML наследник sf::Sprite не рендерится

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml, 2d

У меня есть наследник класса sf::Sprite и он без проблем отрисовывается если я создаю его в main. Однако, когда я пытаюся создать его в другом классе и рисовать несколько штук примерно так:

```
for (auto c : controller.objects) {
    Window.draw(c);
}
```

(где `objects` это вектор), то рендер не дает результата. При том, это не [проблема белого квадрата](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem), квадрата вообще нет

Как это решить?

Comment: Приведите код класса - наследника, а также код main'а и этого класса полностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, дело в том, что у Вашего класса не определён ни конструктор копирования, ни то, что такого конструктора нет, а в данном случае, по логике, должен вызываться именно такой конструктор (если controller.objects это std::vector<наследников sf::Sprite>):

```
for (auto c : controller.objects) {
    Window.draw(c);
}
```

Т.е. в коде `for (auto c : controller.objects)` Вы создаёте не ссылки/указатели на существующие спрайты, а какие-то неинициализированные спрайты, которые, естественно, не имеют ни текстуры, ни прямоугольника - именно поэтому их невозможно отрисовать - как любой свежесозданный sf::Sprite. Попробуйте такой код:

```
sf::RenderWindow window;
sf::Sprite sprite;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML OpenGL"));
   window.clear();
   window.draw(sprite);
   window.display();
   return 0;
}
```

Думаю, Вы увидите ровно то же самое - SFML ничего не нарисует (потому, что спрайт не инициализирован: без текстуры).

Если я прав в том, что controller.objects это std::vector<наследников sf::Sprite>, то заменив `for (auto c : controller.objects)` на `for (auto &c : controller.objects)` (обратите внимание на ссылку: `auto &c`, вместо копии переменной как у Вас `auto c`!) - Вы получите что-то более адекватное - вроде отрисовки Вашего класса-наследника sf::Sprite.

Ещё раз, сравните 2 варианта:
Вариант 1

```
for (auto c : container)
   ...
```

Вариант 2

```
for (auto &c : container)
   ...
```

**Варианты 1 и 2 не тождественны**: в 1м варианте **!!!копируются!!!** элементы (т.е. создаются новые объекты конструктором копирования) из `container` в переменную `c`, а во 2м варианте - **создаются ссылки** на элементы в `container`-е, в виде переменной `c` (т.е. `c` является именно ссылкой на тот или иной объект в контейнере - его адресом, а вовсе не новым объектом того же типа).